# Total orders on subsets

Tags: order-theory

Let $X$ be some finite ground set. Let $\prec$ be a total order on the powerset $\mathcal{P}(X)$, such that if $A\prec A’,B\preceq B’$ and $A\cap B= A’ \cap B’ = \emptyset$, then $A \cup B \prec A’ \cup B’$.

Is there a name for such total orders? Do we always have that there exists some $f:X\to \Bbb{R}$ such that $A \prec B$ if and only if $\sum_{a\in A} f(a) < \sum_{b\in B} f(b)$?

I would also be interested to hear if anything weird occurs when $X$ is infinite.

Comment: I just wrote some (currently inefficient) code for a simulated annealing algorithm where one starts off with any linear ordering on $P(X)$ (for small $X$) and then by repeatedly applying transpositions to the linear ordering, one gradually gets closer and closer to your condition until your condition is satisfied.

Comment: Here is the linear order I got from simulated annealing: [[2,4,5,6],[1,2,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6],[2,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,5,6],[2,4,6],
[2,3,5,6],[1,2,4,6],[1,2,3,5,6],[2,3,4,6],[2,6],[1,2,3,4,6],[1,2,6],[2,4,5],[1,2,4,5],[2,3,6],[1,2,3,6],[2,3,4,5],[2,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,5],[2,4],[2,3,5],[1,2,4],
[1,2,3,5],[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[2],[1,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6],[1,2],[5,6],[2,3],
[1,3,4,5,6],[1,5,6],[1,2,3],[4,6],[3,5,6],[1,4,6],[1,3,5,6],[3,4,6],[6],[1,3,4,6],[1,6],[4,5],[1,4,5],[3,6],[1,3,6],[3,4,5],[5],[1,3,4,5],[1,5],[4],[3,5],[1,4],
[1,3,5],[3,4],[],[1,3,4],[1],[3],[1,3]]

Comment: Given a linear ordering $\prec$, one can try to find your function $f$ using your typical gradient descent or gradient ascent with momentum where we define the loss $L(f)$ by letting $$L(f)=\sum_{A\prec B}\sigma(\sum_{a\in A}f(a)-\sum_{b\in B}f(b)).$$ Here, $\sigma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(0,1)$ can be any order preserving homeomorphism such as the logistic function.

Comment: So I applied my gradient descent to minimize this loss function where the activation function $\sigma$ was simply the logistic function, and I was not able to get L(f) anywhere near zero even for linear orders $\prec$ where $A\prec B$ iff $\sum_{a\in A}g(a)<\sum_{b\in B}g(b)$ for some function $g$. Minimizing the loss function $L(f)$ by gradient descent does not seem to be a good strategy for obtaining the function $f$ if there is one (unless I programmed something wrong).